# How to numerically evaluate index of fixed point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, numerical-calculus, nonlinear-dynamics

I want to take a brute force approach to determining whether a system of 2 ODEs can support oscillations/closed orbits with different combinations of parameters. After a little analysis, I know the system can only have 1 fixed point and, when it exists, I can reliably find it. Now I want to numerically compute its index, but can't figure out how to formulate the integral. I see from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3014943/how-to-calculate-the-index-number-for-a-curve-around-a-linear-systems-fixed-poi) the following integral
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint \frac{\dot{y}\ddot{x} - \dot{x}\ddot{y}}{\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2}dt \, .
$$
Where does this come from? How can I compute this integral for a little circle around a fixed point? Is there any existing code that, given $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$, numerically evaluates such an integral?